# Поменять дату по нажатию на button

Tags: javascript, button, highcharts

Есть график на котором можно выбирать диапазон например с 2010-1-01 по 2020-2-02 . Я попытался сделать чтоб по нажатию на кнопку забивалась конкретная дата типа с 2015-1-10 и по нажатию на button должна по идее забиваться сюда  pointStart:Date.UTC(YY,MM,DD) вот такая дата var YY = 2015 ;var MM = 1 ;var DD = 10 ; но ничего не происходит ( .

```js
 var interval = 3600 * 1000 ;
    var YY = 2014 ;
    var MM = 1 ;  // 0-11
    var DD = 5 ;  // 1-31
   
    var chart11 = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',    
    shadow: {
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)',
            offsetX: 5,
            offsetY: 5,
            opacity: '0.5',
            width: 10
        },        
    renderTo: "chart1",          
    type: "spline"
  },
    rangeSelector: {buttons: [{type: 'day',count: 1,text: 'Д'}, {type: 'week',count: 1,text: 'Н'}, {type: 'month',count: 1,text: 'М'}, {type: 'year',count: 1,text: 'Г'}],buttonTheme: {
                visibility: 'hidden'
            },},
    rangeSelectorTo :{enabled: false,}    ,

    time: {
        
        useUTC: true},  
    title: {
    style:{"fontSize": "27px"} ,
    text: "AG-4"
           },    
    subtitle: {text: ''},
    xAxis: {  
    //allowDecimals: false,    
    //tickInterval: 1 * 3600 * 1000,  
    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000*24*30,    
    type: 'datetime',   
    max: Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1),    
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
    hour: '%H:%M',
    day: '%e. %b',
    week: '%e. %b',
    month: '%b \'%y',
    year: '%Y',    
    //format: '{x:%H:%M}',    
    //day: '%b %e',
    //week: '%b %e' 
       }, 
          },
    yAxis: {
     "fontSize": '21px',
                offset: 45,
                color: '#c9c7c7',
                //min: 0,
                //max: 100,
                //tickInterval: 20,
                labels: {
                formatter: function () {return (this.value > 0 ? '' : '') + this.value + '%';},
                style: {fontSize: '14px',fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',fontWeight: 'bold',}        
                       },
                title: {text: ''}
            },
        
      exporting: {enabled: true,buttons: {contextButton: {menuItems: ['downloadCSV', 'downloadXLS']}}},
      credits: {enabled: false},
      tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '<small>{point.key}</small><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y} %</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        valueDecimals: 2
            },
  legend: {enabled: true},
  plotOptions: {
      series:{
          useUTC: true,
          pointStart:Date.UTC(YY,MM,DD),
          pointInterval: interval
          //tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 ,
          //pointEnd: Date.UTC (2018, 1, 10),
      },
    
      
    area: {
      connectNulls: false,
      stacking: "normal",
      lineColor: "#666666",
      lineWidth: 1,
      marker: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: "#666666"
      }
    }
  },
  series: [
    {color: 'rgba(172,199,255,255)', name: "-10",dataGrouping: {enabled: true},
      data: [34, 21, 20, 20, 19,34, 21, 20, 20, 19,43,87]  },
    {color: 'rgba(188,255,218,255)', name: "10-12,5",dataGrouping: {enabled: true},
      data: [80, 30, 10, 45, 77,80, 30, 10, 45, 77,23,77] },
    {color: 'rgba(200,240,255,255)', name: "12,5-14",dataGrouping: {enabled: true},
      data: [12, 34, 89, 55, 23,12, 34, 89, 55, 23,54,98] },
    {color: 'rgba(255,191,191,255)', name: "14-18",dataGrouping: {enabled: true},
      data: [88, 12, 56, 94, 22,88, 12, 56, 94, 22,34,34] },
    {color: 'rgba(227,208,241,255)', name: "+18",dataGrouping: {enabled: true},
     data: [10, 30, 28, 40, 299,10, 30, 28, 40, 299,44,54] },
  ],
        
    },);
    
    $('#button').click(function() {
     
    var YY = 2015 ;
    var MM = 1 ;  // 0-11
    var DD = 10 ;  // 1-31
    alert ('132');

    chart11.series[0].setData([50, 50, 20, 20, 50,50, 20, 20, 20, 50,50,50],true);
    chart11.series[0].apply(this.pointStart[Date.UTC(2015,1,1)]); 
    
   
    
 
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.15/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>
 <div id="chart1" style="height: 500px; width: 1400px;margin-top: 100px">
 <button id="button" style="position:absolute;left: 1400px;top:180px;z-index: 99999">дата</button>
```

Comment: вы прочитали описание функции [`setData`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData) которую пытаетесь использовать? зачем вы вторым параметром передаете дату, и что вы от этой даты хотите добавиться вообще?

Comment: setData занимается передачей данных .Хотел чтоб данные в переменных YY,MM,DD были заменены на 2015-1-10 .Перепробовал уже кучу вариантов (

Comment: Есть варианты как можно еще по другому сделать ?

Comment: сдалайте сниппет графика и требуемого функиционала, оставьте минимальный код для того чтобы продемонстрировать проблему. У вас тут 70% кода вообще выкинуть можно, они для данного вопроса не имеют значения. Опишите проблему словами понятными не только вам, но и окружающим. Вам надо `pointStart` поменять и график перерисовать по таймеру или чего?

Comment: Да,нужно поменять здесь значение .Думал может по такому принципу chart11.series[0].pointStart:Date.UTC(YY,MM,DD);

Comment: СНИППЕТ  не грузит чего-то

Comment: скрипты highcharts то подключите к сниппету, и должно работать все.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89610/discussion-between-karter-and-teran).